# Run pdflatex.exe from LuaLaTeX document

Tags: pdftex, compiling, pdfpages, shell-escape, lua

My document-combiner combine `pdf`-files via package `pdfpages` using command `\includepdf`. But before including, a source `tex` compiling by `pdflatex.exe` to produce the `pdf`.

But now I have a little trouble, I want to pass some `\LaTeX` command to the `tex` before `pdf` outputing for include.

I need to change this string of my MWE

```
pdflatex.exe -output-directory=\luatexluaescapestring{\fold}  \luatexluaescapestring{\fold/\fold}
```

to

```
pdflatex.exe -output-directory=\luatexluaescapestring{\fold}  "\def\ishandout{1}\luatexluaescapestring{\fold/\fold}"
```

but it does not work

```
\documentclass{article} % combiner
\newcommand{\insertpdf}[1]%
{% #1 is the file name (without extension)
\includepdf[pages=-, link, pagecommand={\pagestyle{plain}}]{#1.pdf}%
    }{\typeout{--- File #1 not found ---}}% 
}
\def\InsertWorkHere#1{%
\edef\fold{#1}
\luadirect{os.execute("

    pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -time-statistics -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=\luatexluaescapestring{\fold}  \luatexluaescapestring{\fold/\fold}

")}
\insertwork{\fold/\fold}
}
\newcommand{\CommandToCompiling}[1]%
{% #1 is the file name (without extension)
    % unknown code here {#1.tex}
    }{\typeout{--- File #1 not found ---}}% 
}
    \begin{document}
    \InsertWorkHere{somefile}

    \end{document}
```

Possible, it is simple to do with `lualatex`. Further, it convenient to connect these commands into one.

Comment: what are the pdf you are trying to include? figures? or whole pages of a document? Do you really want to recompile the included pages every time? Are you using just this lualatex document to put together a bunch of pdfs or will that document have some actual text of its own?

Comment: @ArTourter whole pdf-document createt by pdflatex.exe from sources tex

Comment: the thing I am trying to understand is the reason for the last lualatex step. will the lualatex document that will contain all the other pdflatex document have anything else in it or are you simply using lualatex to collate separate pdf documents?

Comment: @ArTourter I'm using lualatex to combine separate pdf documents into one pdf document (created by lualatex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                           %%
%%    Here command for inserting PDF         %%
%%                                           %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\insertwork}[1]%
{% #1 is the file name (without extension)
    \clearpage
    \renewcommand\worktitle{}% reinitialize
    \IfFileExists{#1.dat}{%
        \input{#1.dat}%
        \phantomsection
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{\worknomber.} \worktitle} 
        \includepdf[pages=-, link, pagecommand={\pagestyle{plain}}]{#1.pdf}%
    }{\typeout{--- File #1 not found ---}}% 
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                     %%
%% Here command for combining PDF's before compilation into PDF-book   %%
%%                                                                     %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%       
\def\InsertWorkHere#1{%
    \edef\fold{#1}
        \newwrite\flags
        \ifx\flag\@empty{%
        \immediate\openout\flags=\fold/flags.tex
        \immediate\write\flags{\string\PassOptionsToClass{MyClassOption1}{MyClass}}
        }%
        \else
        {
        \immediate\openout\flags=\fold/flags.tex
        \immediate\write\flags{\string\PassOptionsToClass{MyClassOption2}{MyClass}}
        }
        \fi
        \immediate\write\flags{\string\PassOptionsToClass{MyClassOption3}{MyClass}}%
        \immediate\closeout\flags
        \def\compile
        {
        \immediate\write18{pdflatex.exe -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory="\fold"  \fold}
        \ifluatex
        \luadirect{
        os.execute("e:/Projects/LaTeX/MyPackage/bin/pax.bat '\luatexluaescapestring{\fold/\fold.pdf}' ")
                  }
        \fi
        \insertwork{\fold/\fold}
        }
        \ifx\cflag\@empty
        \compile
        \else
        \IfFileExists{\fold/\fold.pdf}{\insertwork{\fold/\fold}}{\compile}
        \fi
        %\immediate\write18{e:/Projects/LaTeX/MyPackage/bin/pax.bat "\fold/\fold.pdf"}

        \immediate\write18{del /Q "\fold\/flags.tex"}
        }
```